# how to approach this system of differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

the original system is $$\begin{cases}\dot{x} = y +\cos t \\ \dot{y} = 1 -x\end{cases}$$

it does not look like homogeneous one, so I do not know how to proceed with it. I have never worked wit it.

as for homogeneous I know that we have to:

1.) write down the matrix from the given system

2.) find its eigenvalues and therefore eigenvectors/ generalized eigenvectors

3.) write diwn the answer

---

is there big difference between homogeneous and non-homogeneous systems in solving proccess? And I am also confused about $\cos t$ a lot

Comment: $\ddot{y}=-\dot{x}=-y-\cos t$, so $\ddot{y}+y=-\cos t$. Can you solve this?

Comment: Are you familiar with Laplace transform?

Comment: @MyGlasses, no, our professor did not explain it to us yet

Comment: @woofy, which method did you use to get this?

Comment: @M.Mass I differentiated the second equation with respect to $t$

Comment: @woofy, it seems to be convinient method as it just led to the simple equation, is there any written source about it? (just do not know how to google this method)

Comment: @M.Mass yes, see chapter 26 p.270 of James Robinson's book on ODEs here: https://faculty.mu.edu.sa/public/uploads/1358974368.6105An_Introduction_to_Ordinary_Differential_Equations.pdf

Answer (score 2):

write $$x(t)=1-y'(t)$$ so we have $$x'(t)=-y''(t)$$ plugging this in your first equation you have to solve
$$-y''(t)=y(t)+\cos(t)$$